# PHP - Find the Median of Array with Latitude Longitude

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps, multidimensional-array, latitude-longitude

I have an array of locations with latitude and longitude values and would like to find the location in the array of which its coordinates are in the middle (the **median**). Assume that I have an array that looks like this:

```
$location = [];
$location[0] = [];
$location[0]['name'] = 'Valencia';
$location[0]['latitude'] = 39.46990750;
$location[0]['longitude'] = -0.37628810;
$location[1] = [];
$location[1]['name'] = 'Alanya';
$location[1]['latitude'] = 36.54444300;
$location[1]['longitude'] = 31.99540800;
$location[2] = [];
$location[2]['name'] = 'Side';
$location[2]['latitude'] = 36.77687300;
$location[2]['longitude'] = 31.39764400;
$location[2] = [];
$location[3]['name'] = 'Miami';
$location[3]['latitude'] = 25.79065400;
$location[3]['longitude'] = -80.13004550;
$location[4] = [];
$location[4]['name'] = 'Albufeira';
$location[4]['latitude'] = 37.08907190;
$location[4]['longitude'] = -8.24787960;
```

How can I calculate the median of the latitude/longitude and find the name of the associated location using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array column to isolate the lat and long of the array.
The sort the new arrays and just grab the middle value.

```
$lat = array_column($location, "latitude");
$lon = array_column($location, "longitude");
Sort($lon);
Sort($lat);


Echo "median lat " . $lat[round((count($lat)-1)/2,0)] . "\n";
Echo "median lon " . $lon[round((count($lon)-1)/2,0)] . "\n";
```

https://3v4l.org/p5aLZ

---

I see now that I may have misunderstood the question. You want the complete subarray that is in the middle?

Not sure if this is correct but I calculate lat-lon just to get a number that is in relation to both lat and lon.
Then I grab all the calculated values and save them in two arrays, one which stays as a reference and the other gets sorted.

Then I grab the middle value from the sorted array and use that in array_search on the reference array of calculated values.
This returns the key where the median value was **before** I sorted the array.
Then I just grab the subarray of said key.

```
Foreach($location as &$loc){
    $loc["calc"] = $loc["latitude"] - $loc["longitude"];
}

$sorted = $calc = array_column($location, "calc");
Sort($sorted);

$key = array_search($sorted[round((count($sorted)-1)/2,0)], $calc);
$median = $location[$key];
Var_dump($median);
```

https://3v4l.org/ktnK9